# How to use same jpa repository with multiple databases using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two database environments, one for development  and one for testing.

Both databases having same table structures. I want to show data from specific environment. Environment name will be passed at runtime.

How can I use spring boot same jpa repositories with diff environment?

Comment: sounds like you need to specify runtime environment variables for your application that map to the specific database (test or prod...). e.g. `export APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT=test`

Comment: I have created jpa repository class which connects to dev environment, by default. I want to use the same repository class for test environment as well.So by same way I will be able to connect to multiple environments like prod, Uat, etc

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer that helped you...

Answer (score 0):

You can try with spring boot profiles : Spring Profiles provide a way to segregate parts of your application configuration and make it be available only in certain environments.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Comment: At final stage my application will be deployed to one place, I will have environments dropdown with values dev, testing. 

When I select testing, and hit enter, It should re-use same repository classes, interfaces,  entities and return the data

Answer (score 0):

You need to externalize the database level properties to some property file that will be read from fixed file system path. This property file should not be part of war/jar created. You can change values of property file at time of starting the application. This way, you don't need to make build every time if there is any change in DB environment properties. At any time it is very easy to connect to any new environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` [env. variable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-set-active-spring-profiles) to control your app profiles in run-time.

Don't forget to add to your app different props files related to your Spring profiles, for example:

```
/model
/repositories
/resources
  - application.properties // common properties for both 'dev' and 'prod' profiles
  - application-dev.properties // 'dev' profile properties, for example - of your H2 database
  - application-prod.properties // 'prod' profile properties, for example - of your prod PostgreSQL database
```

Note that you can run your app also like this:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev target/my-app.jar
java -jar target/my-app.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Set your active profile in your IDE (for [example](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-spring-boot.html#d621416e17)) to run app with this profile in IDE.

Set your 'default' profile in the `application.properties`:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```